# I wish there was?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Abigail Adams wrote to John Adams when he was at Philadelphia for Second Continental Congress in 1776.
"I wish most sincerely there was not a slave in the province.  It always seemed a most iniquitous scheme to me to fight ourselves for what we’re daily robbing and plundering from those who have as good a right to freedom as we have."

It caught my attention with the sentence "I wish ... there **was** not..?"  Shouldn't it have been "there were not a slave?"  Maybe it was a simple typo or maybe that's how they wrote back then.

By the way, I am in no way trying to belittle her English ability here.  She was one of the greatest New Englanders in her generation I know.

Any comment?

Comment: All forms of _be_ have been regularizing for centuries, and the counterfactual use of plural past forms of auxiliary _be_ in cases where the actual subject is a dummy _there_ and the displaced subject is a negative -- neither one providing any natural number to agree with -- seems way overformal, especially in personal correspondence, and had already become optional. Just another milestone in the ongoing death of English inflections. Of course, they didn't realize their words were going to used to instruct children to practice zombie English rules.

Comment: It may seem "way over-formal" ***now***. It wasn't then, and the question is valid. What is interesting is that where *were* might be expected in 1776, the writer has *was*. I wonder why that is.

Comment: That's the way I'd write it now.  It may make more sense to you if you read "I wish ... there was not a *single* slave in the province."

Answer (score 0):

Wishing usually suggests a subjunctive mood.  Something may or may not happen. So, for example, *I wish I were a millionaire*.

The example we are given here

"*I wish most sincerely there was not a slave.*.."

is a (hopeless) wish for something that is NOT the case - there are, in fact, many slaves in the province.  Therefore the wishing has no possibility of being true and the reality - there are slaves - means that the speaker needs must acknowledge this and use the indicative ('was') rather than the subjunctive ('were') mood.